# Are there yajnas in the Vedas to prevent seduction by Gandharvas and Apsaras?

Tags: atharva-veda, gandharva, apsaras

There are many stories in Hindu scriptures of Apsaras seducing men.

Are there any incantations and rituals one can do to prevent these beings from seducing humans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there yajnas in the Vedas to prevent seduction by Gandharvas and Apsaras?

**Yes, from the [Atharva Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe42/av050.htm):**

> 5. Where your gold and silver swings are, where cymbals and lutes chime together, pass away there Apsaras, since you have been recognised.
>
> ...
>
> 7. Of the crested Gandharva, the husband of the Apsaras, who comes dancing here, I crush the two mushkas and cut off the penis.
> 8. Terrible are the missiles of Indra, with a hundred points, brazen; with these he shall pierce the Gandharvas, who devour oblations, and devour the avakâ-reed.
>
> ...
>
> 11. One is like a dog, one like an ape. As a youth, with luxuriant locks, pleasant to look upon, the Gandharva hangs about the woman. Him do we drive out from here with our powerful charm.
> 12. The Apsaras, you know, are your wives; you, the Gandharvas, are their husbands. Speed away, you immortals, do not go after mortals!